# etrade scraping with python requests doesn't want to work with cross-domain urls

Tags: python, cookies, cross-domain, python-requests

Trying to scrape some basic stock info from etrade (I know they have an api but I want to figure this scraping out first) and I can get past the login with the requests module with this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
symbol = 'A'
payload = {'USER':etradeUsername, 'PASSWORD':etradePassword, 'countrylangselect':'us_english', 'TARGET':'/e/t/pfm/portfolioview'}
with requests.Session() as c:
    c.post('https://us.etrade.com/login.fcc', data=payload)
    r=c.get('https://us.etrade.com/e/t/pfm/portfolioview')
    #r=c.get('https://www.etrade.wallst.com/v1/stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?symbol=' + symbol + '&rsO=new')

    etradeMarkup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    #print r.headers
    file1 = open("etrade.html","w")
    file1.write("<html><body><head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head>" + str(etradeMarkup.prettify().encode("utf-8")) + "</body></html>")
    file1.flush()
    file1.close()
```

The file write is for me to see what the scraper gets.

I can see the portfolio page just fine so I know that the login is working.  The next line that is commented out is my goal page to scrape.  I can see the www.etrade.wallst.com... page after a successful login with my browser but the scraper just gets redirected to the etrade.com login page.

I think there is a session transfer or cookie variable that is moving between domains that my browser knows how to handle but my code doesn't.

I'm at a dead-end with my python and http knowledge and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to figure out how to program past this difficulty.

Thank you very much for any help you can offer.
(new to python and scraping so please be kind :)

Comment: There's a reasonable chance it doesn't like you self-identifying as a robot.  See if fudging the `User-Agent` header does anything.

Comment: @roippi I've tried a couple of different headers by adding the lines

c.headers.update({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36','Referer':'https://us.etrade.com/e/t/pfm/portfolioview'})

Which didn't change anything.  Then I tried an IE10 User-Agent:
c.headers.update({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.6; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; InfoPath.2; SLCC1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727) 3gpp-gba UNTRUSTED/1.0'})

and this didn't help either.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that there is another page from which cookies need to be set. I was assuming the push to the etrade login page was due to needing cookies from the post-login part of etrade but I was wrong.  I don't need the etrade login at all for this page, just another page to get cookies.  By adding the line to view https://us.etrade.com/e/t/invest/markets?ploc=c-MainNav I was able to get the data that was needed to view the goal page without it forcing my program back to the login page.

```
with requests.Session() as c:

    #  adding this line was the key
    c.get('https://us.etrade.com/e/t/invest/markets?ploc=c-MainNav') 

    r=c.get('https://www.etrade.wallst.com/v1/stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?symbol=' + symbol + '&rsO=new')

    etradeMarkup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```